# Can someone tell me the handlebar diameter of a Carerra TDF road bike from Halfords

Tags: handlebars

Does anyone know or can measure the diameter of the handlebars for the Carerra TDF road bike from Halfords.

It was bought a few years ago and the similar specs on the site aren't helpful.

This would be at the point where you'd fit cross top levers, so not at the stem.

**Update.** It's not my bike hence why I can't measure it. Otherwise I wouldn't be asking. Hoping someone has it and can measure or already knows.

**Update 2.** I'd hoped to get lucky and that someone here had this bike. Is anyone good at *eyeballing the diameter from a video*?

Comment: If you don't own a calliper  (there are really cheap ones around) you can alternatively measure the circumference and divide by 3.14.

Comment: See edit. Not my bike I'm afraid

Comment: begs the question - Why do you want to find its handlebar diameter, if you can't access the bike ?   Why can't you get the current owner to measure it?

Comment: It's a christmas present. That would ruin the surprise.

Comment: I clarified the title which is misleading, but because it now (accurately) reflects the content, this is likely to be closed as too specific to your particular model.

Comment: @RoboKaren The title was wrongly edited by someone, thanks for putting it back. Are we not supposed to ask questions about specific bikes?

Comment: @Adam - someone pedantic might flag to close it. I think it's ok but at the same time, unlikely to get many satisfying answers as it'd require someone to have the same bike to answer it.

Comment: @RoboKaren I see it all the time; I was hoping it was popular enough that someone would have it. I've edited a video link, just in case someone can tell by looking.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have access to calipers? Similar to [these](https://www.amazon.com/digital-calipers/b?node=2476630011). (Pretty handy device to have around if not).

Otherwise, you could take a small string and wrap it around the bars put a mark at the point of overlap, measure with a ruler, then put that high school math to use (diameter = circumference / pi)

Comment: See edit. Not my bike I'm afraid

Answer (score 2):

Based on your video, its a 1" / 25.4 mm diameter handlebar.  Simply keep the receipt/exchange card as a contingency plan.

Or consider giving a gift voucher instead so cyclist can buy exactly what they want.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get a picture of the bike to eyeball 25.4/26(~1") vs 31.8(~1 1/4"), which would rule out 2 of the three, also making sure its a round clamping surface, most low end cross top levers as well as clip on aerobars come with shims, if that's your intention.

Comment: I can find pictures, but I can't tell. Can you tell from the video in my edit?